# Who builds aircraft faster, Boeing or Airbus?

Tags: aircraft-manufacturer

Setting aside recent Boeing MAX crisis and post pandemic manufacturing issues, who was overall delivering aircraft faster before 2019, Boeing or Airbus?

*PS:* If you want to pick a specific model, Let's consider their most popular version for comparison,  B737 vs A320 .

Comment: Whatever the current rate of production for Boeing aircraft is, it is too fast for safety.

Comment: unfortunately indeed

Comment: @Gabe with their quality standards nowadays, probably building 1 aircraft per month would be too fast.

Answer (score 3):

Airbus claims that it takes 1 month for the final assembly of an A320 and from manufacturing of first part to completed aircraft it takes 1 year. This is probably because Airbus has various factories all across Europe to build the planes.

After the fuselage is brought over by train, Boeing has claimed that it only takes 9 days to assemble the aircraft. They are currently planning to make 42 737s per month from February.

From a pretty long time, Airbus has had an edge over Boeing in terms of A320 per month, currently it seems to be approximately 45-60.

Sources -
[Boeing 737 in 9 days after receiving fuselage](https://www.wired.com/2016/09/boeing-builds-737-just-nine-days/)

[Airbus A320 per month figures (Aug 23)](https://flightplan.forecastinternational.com/2023/09/14/airbus-and-boeing-report-august-2023-commercial-aircraft-orders-and-deliveries/)

[Time taken for A320 manufacturing](https://www.airbus.com/sites/g/files/jlcbta136/files/2022-01/EN-Airbus-A320-Facts-and-Figures-January-2022.pdf)

PS: I see now that the question was asking about pre-2019 production  rates, from some reasearch I've done it can be seen that Airbus was still a bit ahead of Boeing in 2019 but Boeing was certainly more competitive than it is now.